# Object of type UserForm is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django

I am running a django application . I have an error :

```
TypeError: Object of type UserForm is not JSON serializable
```

Below is the code:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.Form):
username=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta():
         model=User
         fields=('username','password')
```

views.py:

```
def signup(request):
    registered=False
    failed_ref=False
    wrong_ref=False
    if request.method=='POST':
       user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
       if user_form.is_valid():
          user = user_form.save()
          user.set_password(user.password)
          user.save()
    user_form=UserForm()
    return JsonResponse({'user_form':user_form,'registered':registered,
                                                    'failed_ref':failed_ref,'wrong_ref':wrong_ref})
```

How to make this form JSON serializable?

Comment: Why you want to serialize form object in the first place?

Comment: simultaneously we are developing Android application . So for that we need to get JSON response .

Comment: You can't do both at once. You should have one view for the JSON api, and another view for the web form.

Comment: ok so i should not use forms.py for getting JSON response?

Comment: If you're handling the data as json, you probably would not want or need to use a Django form. If you're handling the data as standard HTML post data, you probably would not want or need to use a JSON response. You definitely cannot serialize (at least without a lot of extra work) a Django form object to JSON.

Comment: instead of using form use serializers
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#example

Answer (score 0):

Forms are used for "user interfaces" (user that set behind his/her PC and fill in the form). For mobile apps (or web apps) you should have in your backend an "application programming interface (API)" that can communicate with these systems (e.g mobile apps).

This API simply receive the data (for instance  User Info) from the request body (maybe as `JSON`) e.g:

`{"email": "an emai", "pass": "secret"}`.

So the request for you signup endpoint may be of the form:

```
POST: your_host:your_port/users or 
{"email": "an emai", "pass": "secret"...}
```

When separating backend from frontend, backend is not more involved how the Information are received as long as it is in the correct format (e.g `JSON`), so data may be the result of user filling a form or as result of an AJAX call or through POSTMAN...etc.

So you function may need to rewritten into something like that:

```
def signup(request):
    registered=False
    failed_ref=False
    wrong_ref=False
    if request.method=='POST':
       user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
       if user_form.is_valid():
          user = user_form.save()
          user.set_password(user.password)
          user.save()
          return HttpResponse(status=200)
       eles:
           return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

**Note**: this code is just exemplary and it is better to use something like `django rest framework`.